# Explain why a chi-square random variable will approximately have a normal distribution for large n

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Explain why a chi-square random variable having n degrees of freedom will approximately have the distribution of a normal random variable when n is large.

Answer (score 3):

Because a chi-square random variable $X_n$ with $n$ degrees of freedom is distributed like $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nY_k^2$ with $(Y_k)_{k\geqslant1}$ i.i.d. standard normal hence $X_n=n+\sqrt{2n}Z_n$ where $Z_n$ converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable when $n\to\infty$, by the usual central limit theorem applied to the sequence $(Y_k^2)_{k\geqslant1}$.